# PDFBox reads an empty string when I try to read a PDF

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to use pdf box to read text from a file in order to sort it in the file system. I am using C#. I can read example pdf's from the internet, but for some reason, the pdfs I'm trying to read from only returns a string with no real characters in it. Here is the code I am using:

```
using org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel;
using org.apache.pdfbox.util;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PDFBoxTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = @"C:\Users\Development\Desktop\purchaseOrder.pdf";

            PDDocument doc = null;
            try
            {
                doc = PDDocument.load(fileName);
                PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                Console.WriteLine(stripper.getText(doc));   
            }
            finally

            {
                if (doc != null)
                {
                    doc.close();
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
       }
   }
}
```

Here is the link to the pdf's which won't work for me. One was saved, the other was printed using the "Letter" setting.

Thanks in advance!
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iSadM0ikdrhHsvemNVdyEl3BeTIhm39U?usp=sharing

Comment: Please read the text extraction FAQ: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#text-extraction . Were you able to get any text from Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 2):

Your PDFs do not contain any text.

Yes, when you open the PDFs in a viewer, you *see* text. But this text is not generated using *text drawing instructions* in the PDFs but instead using *path drawing instructions*, i.e. each and every letter you see is explicitly constructed using a set of curves and lines defining the outlines of the respective letter which then is filled with color.

Thus, your PDFs do not contain any text but a lot of arbitrary small filled paths.

Text extraction, on the other hand, works by analyzing *text drawing instructions* which as an argument have the encoded text in question. Thus text extraction won't find any text in your PDFs.

The technique used in your PDFs actually is usually used to *prevent others from extracting the text* content of their PDF, be it using text extraction classes like the `PDFTextStripper`, or using copy&paste from a PDF viewer, or using assistive technologies like screen readers for visually impaired users.

For such PDFs, therefore, you have to either resort to generic OCR (i.e. render the PDF as a bitmap image and apply a standard OCR application to the images) or specialized OCR (i.e. some custom program taking the path definitions and trying to recognize characters from path definitions).

I don't know any program of the latter kind, I merely consider it a possibly sensible approach if one has to deal with many such PDFs.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm not sure how hard it would be to do this. All I need from the document is the PO#, Lot #, and activity. Thanks a bunch.